# [ROS 2] How to start and stop a node from a Python script?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Context**: I am running a camera using ROS. To facilitate data collection I integrated a PySimpleGui graphical user interface inside a Node, so I can start streaming, recording or playing back data through a user-friendly interface.

**Expected behaviour**:  Therefore, my goal is to execute a Node, when the user clicks on a button. For instance, if the following minimal example, I want to start a publisher Node when the user clicks on the button 'Talk'. And I want to start a subscriber Node when the user clicks on 'Listen'.

**Platform** : I run ROS2 humble on WSL2 - Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

**Code**: Here is `GUI publisher`, which will publish a string corresponding to the button name to the topic \gui_command when the user clicks on a button.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from std_msgs.msg import String

def generate_layout():
    layout = [[sg.Button('Talk'), sg.Button('Listen'), sg.Button('Exit')]]
    return layout

class MinimalGuiPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('gui')

        # Initialization of the GUI
        self.layout = generate_layout()
        self.window = sg.Window('Camera recording', self.layout, location=(800, 400), finalize=True)
        self.values, self.event = None, ''

        # Initialization of the publisher
        self.publisher_ = self.create_publisher(String, 'gui_command', 10)
        timer_period = 0.2
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.gui_callback)

    def gui_callback(self):
        msg = String()

        # Check for any event
        self.event, self.values = self.window.read()
        print(self.event)

        msg.data = str(self.event)

        self.publisher_.publish(msg)
        self.get_logger().info('Publishing: "%s"' % msg.data)

        if self.event in ('Exit', None):
            print('User clicked on Exit')
            exit()

def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_publisher = MinimalGuiServer()

    rclpy.spin(minimal_publisher)

    minimal_publisher.destroy_node()

    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the `GUI subscriber` that listens to the command through subscription to the topic \gui_command.

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

from std_msgs.msg import String


class MinimalGuiClient(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('gui_client')
        self.subscription = self.create_subscription(
            String,
            'gui_command',
            self.listener_callback,
            10)
        self.subscription  # prevent unused variable warning

    def listener_callback(self, msg):
        recorder = None
        self.get_logger().info('User clicked on: "%s"' % msg.data)

        if msg.data in ('Exit', 'None'):
            exit()

        elif msg.data == 'Talk':
            ###### Here start the talker like it would with
            ###### ros2 run py_pubsub talker
            pass

        elif msg.data == 'Listen':
            ###### Here start the talker like it would with
            ###### ros2 run py_pubsub listener
            pass


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    minimal_subscriber = MinimalGuiClient()

    rclpy.spin(minimal_subscriber)

    minimal_subscriber.destroy_node()

    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Question** : Is it possible to program the execution of a Node from another Node? If yes, could you please indicate which is the correct way to do so?

I tried to read the doc, and thought about using `ros2launch` (edited). But it is not clear to me if and how a node or a launch can be triggered by user interaction. Your help would be very much appreciated !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412104/%5Bros-2%5D-how-to-start-and-stop-a-node-from-a-python-script?/) by [rmapsps](https://answers.ros.org/users/136146/rmapsps/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2023-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you ljaniec for your answer. In case someone stumbles on a similar issue here is how I solved my problem.

After navigating the ROS2 documentation, I discovered the concept of lifecycle nodes. Here are a few links that helped me understand how to use it :

- **Lifecycle node state graph design** : http://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html
- **Lifecycle talker examples**: https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/humble/lifecycle_py/lifecycle_py/talker.py
- **Launch file examples integrating lifecycle nodes**: https://github.com/ros2/launch_ros/tree/rolling/ros2launch/examples
- **Event handlers** :
  https://answers.ros.org/question/304370/ros2-launch-how-to-correctly-create-a-lifecycle-launch-file/
- **Callback groups**:  https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/How-To-Guides/Using-callback-groups.html

The main idea is to create a lifecycle node with different states. The `main_gui.py` script controls the states. And the talker lifecycle node will publish when it is in the `activate` state. And stop publishing in the `deactivate` state.

`main_gui.py` - Adapted from : https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/humble/lifecycle_py/lifecycle_py/talker.py

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.lifecycle import Node
from rclpy.lifecycle import State
from rclpy.lifecycle import TransitionCallbackReturn
from std_msgs.msg import String

class LifecycleTalker(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('play_button')

        self.pub = None
        self.timer = None
        self._count = 0

    def publish(self):
        """Publish a new message when enabled."""
        msg = String()
        msg.data = "Lifecycle HelloWorld #" + str(self._count)
        self._count += 1

        # Only if the publisher is in an active state, the message transfer is
        # enabled and the message actually published.
        if self.pub is not None:
            self.pub.publish(msg)
            self.get_logger().info(f'Lifecycle publisher is active. Published: [{msg.data}]')

    def on_configure(self, state: State) -> TransitionCallbackReturn:
        self.pub = self.create_lifecycle_publisher(String, "lifecycle_chatter", 10)

        self.get_logger().info("on_configure() is called.")
        return super().on_configure(state)

    def on_activate(self, state: State) -> TransitionCallbackReturn:
        # Log, only for demo purposes
        self.get_logger().info("on_activate() is called.")
        self.timer = self.create_timer(1.0, self.publish)

        return super().on_activate(state)

    def on_deactivate(self, state: State) -> TransitionCallbackReturn:
        self.get_logger().info("on_deactivate() is called.")
        self.destroy_timer(self.timer)
        return super().on_deactivate(state)

    def on_cleanup(self, state: State) -> TransitionCallbackReturn:
        self.destroy_timer(self.timer)
        self.destroy_publisher(self.pub)

        self.get_logger().info('on_cleanup() is called.')
        return super().on_cleanup(state)

    def on_shutdown(self, state: State) -> TransitionCallbackReturn:
        self.destroy_timer(self.timer)
        self.destroy_publisher(self.pub)

        self.get_logger().info('on_shutdown() is called.')
        return super().on_shutdown(state)


def main():
    rclpy.init()

    executor = rclpy.executors.SingleThreadedExecutor()
    lc_node = LifecycleTalker()
    executor.add_node(lc_node)
    try:
        executor.spin()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, rclpy.executors.ExternalShutdownException):
        lc_node.destroy_node()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`main_gui.py`

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from rclpy.callback_groups import ReentrantCallbackGroup
from rclpy.executors import ExternalShutdownException

from lifecycle_msgs.srv import ChangeState
from lifecycle_msgs.msg import Transition


def minimal_layout():
    layout = [[sg.Button('Talk'), sg.Button('Exit')]]
    return layout


    class MainGui(Node):
    
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__('gui_client')
    
            # Initialization of the GUI
            self.layout = minimal_layout()
            self.window = sg.Window('Lifecycle GUI', self.layout, location=(800, 400), finalize=True)
            self.values, self.event = None, ''
    
            # Initialization of the publisher
            timer_period = 0.1
            self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.gui_callback)
    
            # Node's default callback group is mutually exclusive. This would prevent the client response
            # from being processed until the timer callback finished, but the timer callback in this
            # example is waiting for the client response
            self.cb_group = ReentrantCallbackGroup()
    
            # Initialize the change_state_client that will update the talker state
            self.change_talking_state_cli = self.create_client(ChangeState, '/talker/change_state',
                                                               callback_group=self.cb_group)
            # Transition to configured state
            self.req = ChangeState.Request()
            self.req.transition = Transition(label='configure')
    
            # Call the on_configure state
            future = self.change_talking_state_cli.call_async(self.req)
            rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)
    
            # Initialize the variable that will monitor the talker state
            self.is_talking = False
    
        async def gui_callback(self):
            self.event, self.values = self.window.read(timeout=10)
    
            if self.event in ('Exit', 'None'):
                exit()
    
            elif self.event == 'Talk':
                ######  Here start the talker like it would with `ros2 run py_pubsub talker`
    
                # Update the transition according to current button state
                next_talking_transition = 'activate' if not self.is_talking else 'deactivate'
    
                # Create the change state object
                self.req.transition = Transition(label=next_talking_transition)
    
                # Call to the service
                future_lifecycle = self.change_talking_state_cli.call_async(self.req)
                result_change_state = await future_lifecycle
    
                # If the request was successful, update the streaming status
                if result_change_state.success:
                    self.is_talking = not self.is_talking
                    button_color = sg.theme_button_color() if not self.is_talking else 'red'
                    self.window['Talk'].update(button_color=button_color)
    
    
    def main(args=None):
        rclpy.init(args=args)
    
        # Create the node
        minimal_subscriber = MainGui()
    
        try:
            # Spin the node so the callback function is called.
            rclpy.spin(minimal_subscriber)
    
        except (KeyboardInterrupt, ExternalShutdownException):
            # If the node receive a KeyboardInterrupt command
            pass
    
        finally:
            # Destroy the node explicitly
            # (optional - Done automatically when node is garbage collected)
            minimal_subscriber.destroy_node()
            rclpy.shutdown()
    
        rclpy.shutdown()
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

`main.launch.py`

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import EmitEvent
from launch.events import Shutdown
from launch_ros.actions import Node, LifecycleNode


def generate_launch_description():
    ld = LaunchDescription()

    gui_node = LifecycleNode(
        package='minimal_examples',
        executable='main_gui',
        name='main_gui',
        namespace='',
        output='screen',
        on_exit=EmitEvent(event=Shutdown(reason='Window closed'))
    )

    lifecycle_talker_node = LifecycleNode(
        package='minimal_examples',
        executable='lifecycle_talker',
        name='talker',
        namespace='',
        output='screen'
    )

    ld.add_action(gui_node)
    ld.add_action(lifecycle_talker_node)

    return ld
```

`setup.py`

```
import os
from glob import glob
from setuptools import setup


package_name = 'minimal_examples'

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=[package_name],
    data_files=[
        ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
         ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
        # Include all launch files.
        (os.path.join('share', package_name), glob('launch/*launch.[pxy][yma]*'))
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    description='Packages that includes minimal example for the ROS forum',
    license='Apache License 2.0',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'main_gui = minimal_examples.main_gui:main',
            'lifecycle_talker = minimal_examples.lifecycle_nodes:main'
        ],
    },
)
```

If you want to monitor the topic, run : `ros2 topic echo /lifecycle_chatter`

---

Originally posted by [rmapsps](https://answers.ros.org/users/136146/rmapsps/) with karma: 21 on 2023-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2023-02-22**:
Really nice solution, I hadn't thought of Lifecycle Nodes but they fit perfectly there, well done!